# Uploadify: File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0

Tags: php, upload, uploadify

I am experiencing the following error with uploadify and uploadifive:

```
PHP Warning:  File upload error - unable to create a temporary file in Unknown on line 0
```

This is an intermittent issue.  Sometimes uploads work OK, sometimes not.  Up until yesterday all was working well, and I am not aware of having made any changes to uploadify or uploadifive.  At the front end it appears that uploads have completed successfully, i.e. no errors are reported and the `onQueueComplete` event fires, but files are not showing in my upload folder, and the error above shows in my `error_log`.

I'm wondering what I can do to troubleshoot this issue.

---

**ADDITIONAL SESSION ERRORS:**

```
PHP Warning: session_start() [<a href='function.session-start'>function.session-start</a>]: open(/tmp/sess_6d08c1a8c3703bb08a3dc585e1828109, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in /home/..../uploadifive.php on line 6

PHP Warning: Unknown: open(/tmp/sess_6d08c1a8c3703bb08a3dc585e1828109, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in Unknown on line 0

PHP Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that your `/tmp` has space issues.

You can check the disc space size by running `df -h` on the console.

If you cannot clear the `/tmp` space issue, you could consider moving the temporary upload file path: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir

Comment: Thanks. I am a newbie when it comes to these matters, so have a couple of newbie questions.  how do I run the console (I'm on a Mac if this makes any difference?). Regarding moving the temporary upload file path, I don't have access to php.ini as I'm on a shared server.  Can I create a separate php.ini file to override the path to the temp dir, and if so, where would I put this file on my server?

Comment: @nick if you're getting these errors on your shared host you better contact the provider.

Comment: Thanks again Jack. My provider got back to me to say the issue is fixed, and uploads are working fine now, so it was a server issue.

Comment: @Nick great! glad to hear your problems are over :)

Answer (score 1):

`unable to create a temporary file in Unknown` implies that your temp path isn't set, or can't be read. Try restarting your server and try again. If that doesn't work, check that your php.ini has a temp path set.

Comment: Thanks.  I just got my host to restart my server, but that didn't help.  My site is on a shared server, so I presume I don't have access to php.ini.  I will contact the host again, asking them to check if a temp path is set.

Comment: The host has stated "the tmp folder will be set fine to the user in our servers".  I am going to post a ticket with the host so that it gets escalated to a more senior technician.

Answer (score 0):

Check the permissions of the tmp folder.

Comment: By tmp folder do you mean the 'tmp' folder in the root of my server?  If so, permissions are 755.  Also I am now seeing other errors, which I have added to the question above.

Comment: The additional errors disappear when I disable the session_start() on uploadifive.php.  I still get the main error though.

Comment: according with you ADDITIONAL SESSION ERRORS:

PHP Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: open(/tmp/sess_6d08c1a8c3703bb08a3dc585e1828109, O_RDWR) failed: No space left on device (28) in /home/..../uploadifive.php on line 6, the permission is not main reason. i think the jack answers is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Check the disc space size by running df -h

check the root volume, try to clear unwanted files or increase the space.
This fixed the issue for me